# Is the interior of a set contained in the derived set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it true that $A^° \subseteq A'$ given a set $A$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ ?

This question has probably been asked before, but oddly enough I haven't found it. Does this property hold?

Comment: I think this answers your question, right? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965561/interior-and-accumulation-points#:~:text=Any%20point%20x%20that%20belongs,E%20contains%20infinitely%20many%20points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true for very separated metric spaces. For example, if $X$ has the discrete metric where $\text{int}(A)=A$ for every $A\subseteq X$. Also if the space has an [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point), the singleton does not satisfy this.

In fact if you assume that the set $A$ has no isolated points, then the set itself satisfies $A\subseteq A$. This is since when denoting $I(A)$ to be the subset of isolated points in $A$, you always have that $\overline{A}=A'\cup I(A)$, as you can see  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point#Properties).